# Why $\mathbb{Z/nZ} \to \mathbb{Z} $ is not order preserving?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb{Z/nZ} \to \mathbb{Z} $ is a group homomorphism. But order of any element in $\mathbb{Z/nZ}$ is finite and order of any element in $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite.  How possible $\infty|\text{finite}$ ?

Comment: The order of any *nonzero* element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. A careful rephrasing of what you've written above shows that the only group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the one which sends every element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to zero in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi:\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z$ is a homomorphism, then $$0=\phi(n)=n\phi(1)$$

What can you conclude about either $n$ or $\phi(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

You have it backwards.  For finite groups, the order of an element in the target group divides the order of an element in the original group.  For example, we can have a group homomorphism $\Bbb {Z/42Z \to Z/6Z}$  The elements of order $42$ in $\Bbb {Z/42Z}$ go to elements of order $6$ in $\Bbb {Z/6Z}$.  The correspoinding thing would be $finite|\infty$, which is not so surprising.